# Joomla 4 addfieldpath

Tags: jform, form-fields-types, joomla-4.x

Has the `addfieldpath` parameter in custom extension forms changed in Joomla 4? The Joomla admin is no longer finding my component's customized field types.

I'm using `addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/Field">` in the form xml definition, since all my fields have been moved to the new `Field` directory, and my field names have been changed to something like `HeaderField` and are referenced in the XML field like:

`<field name="header" type="header" default="COM_MYCOMPONENT_DEFAULT" description="COM_MYCOMPONENT_DESC" tag="info" />`

I'm not sure if there's something that has to be done to let the xml form correctly map to the new namespaced fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new format appears to be `addfieldprefix` instead of `addfieldpath`, using the namespace for your `Field` directory: `addfieldprefix="MyCompany\Component\MyComponent\Administrator\Field"`